# Return list of members which are instances of a class template

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I have something like this:

```cpp
class BaseClass {
public:
 BaseClass(ValueType::Enum valueType);

protected:
 ValueType::Enum valueType;
};

template<typename T>
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
public:
 DerivedClass(ValueType::Enum valueType, T value);

 T getValue();

private:
 T value;
};

class SomeOtherClass {
public:
 SomeOtherClass(DerivedClass<std::string> str1, DerivedClass<int> nr1);

private:
 DerivedClass<std::string> str1;
 DerivedClass<int> nr1;
};
```

Is there a way to return a list of all member of SomeOtherClass?
Something like:

```cpp
template<typename T>
std::list<DerivedClass<T>> getMember() {
 return {str1, nr1};
}
```

I also want to be able to call `getValue()` for each list entry.

Would appreciate any help with this, I am currently unsure if what I want is even possible in C++.

Comment: _class template_, not "template class". When you fill out the template parameters, it becomes a completely new class. `DerivedClass<std::string>` and `DerivedClass<int>` are completely different classes and cannot be held together in a container like that. But you can return a `std::list<BaseClass*>` if you want. However, it's questionable what good that will do when you have no polymorphic methods. There will almost certainly be a C++ approach for whatever underlying problem you're trying to solve, but currently this looks like [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/200806)

Comment: You can do the reverse thing! Instead of typing all different types inside your class declaration, you can use a typelist and expand the typelist where you want, e.g. in you constructor and in the member part. So you define the types once and can get that typelist back also. Macros are not your friend in 2022!

Comment: @paddy I guess you're right, there probably will be a C++ approach to solve my underlying problem. I think I kinda got lost in my current solution and lost track of my actual problem. I think I'll rethink my approach and come up with something else.

Comment: What do you want to do with such a list? Before asking yourself "how can I build X", ans yourself "what do I want to do with X". This pretty much dictates what X can and cannot be.

Answer (score 0):

You could have used [`std::tuple`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple).

```
class SomeOtherClass {
public:
    SomeOtherClass(DerivedClass<std::string> str1, DerivedClass<int> nr1);

    std::tuple<DerivedClass<std::string>, DerivedClass<int>> get_members()
    {
        return std::make_tuple(str1, nr1);
    }

private:
    DerivedClass<std::string> str1;
    DerivedClass<int> nr1;
};
```

Compiled for me [here](https://godbolt.org/z/b6WM5hY7j).

Comment: `std::tie` might be more appropriate (so tuple of reference).

Comment: *"I also want to be able to call `getValue()` for each list entry."*. So, then `std::apply([](auto&... members){ ((std::cout << members.getValue() << std::endl), ...); }, someOtherClass.get_members())` usage.